# Whats difference between dependency management and build management tool?

Tags: java, php, maven, dependency-management

I'm PHP Developer & new to Java I'm learning these concepts.

I heard Maven is exactly what the composer do in PHP, but the composer is a "Dependency management tool" but Maven is called "Build Management tool", Can someone explain the difference between dependency management and build management tool?

Answer (score 3):

Maven can be both used as dependency management and build management. "DM" is about registering which external artifacts (jar files) you need in your code while "BM" is about preparing the packaging and how will be the final output (e.g. jar, war, etc.). Maven can do both, there is dependency list and also build section where you can define the final output packaging and even distribution.